# Security Violation : SonaType violations received due to siddhi-io-googlepubsub dependency

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka-connect, google-cloud-pubsub

While building Google Cloud PubSub - Kafka [connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/pubsub/tree/master/kafka-connector) and running SonaType IQ scan reports multiple security vulnerabilities due to org.wso2.extension.siddhi.io.googlepubsub:siddhi-io-googlepubsub.
We tried multiple scenarios and this depency is only pulled when we use these 3 dependencies together :

- com.google.cloud:google-cloud-pubsub
- com.google.apis:google-api-services-pubsub.
- io.grpc:grpc-all
- org.mockito:mockito-core

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by old dependencies being pulled into the [Cloud Pub/Sub Kafka Connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/pubsub/tree/master/kafka-connector). An [update of the dependencies](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/pubsub/pull/220) fixed it.